# Multiple observables one subscriber

Tags: rx-java

I need to consume events from multiple sources. Amount of sources varies, a source may be dinamically added or removed.

As I want a possibility to change set of sources 'on the fly', without need to resubscribe, `merge` is not a case.

Have tried something like

```
PublishSubject<Integer> sourcesSubject = PublishSubject.create();

sourcesSubject.subscribe(...);

Observable<Integer> source1 = ...;
source1.subscribe(sourcesSubject); // add first source

Observable<Integer> source2 = ...;
source2.subscribe(sourcesSubject); // add second source

..... // How to remove a source?
```

but have no idea how to remove a source.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. What is the reason you want this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to look at combining operators like `merge` (and instance variant `mergeWith`) or `concat` (`concatWith`) which will remove the need to use `Subject`. When you unsubscribe all the sources will be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Have found the simplest way to remove source:

```
Observable<Integer> source = ...;
Subscription subscription = source.subscribe(sourcesSubject); // add source
subscription.unsubscribe(); // remove source
```